# Adding an endAdornment to the @mui/material TextField component breaks its custom styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I used the CSS Validation Style TextField from this example https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#customization and simply added an endAdornment to it. Now the custom styling is completely ignored. Do I have to add something in addition or is this just broken?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";

const ValidationTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& input:valid + fieldset": {
    borderColor: "green",
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  "& input:invalid + fieldset": {
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  "& input:valid:focus + fieldset": {
    borderLeftWidth: 6,
    padding: "4px !important" // override inline-style
  }
});

export default function CustomizedInputs() {
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      noValidate
      sx={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: { sm: "1fr 1fr" },
        gap: 2
      }}
    >
      <ValidationTextField
        label="CSS validation style"
        required
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue="Success"
        id="validation-outlined-input"
      />
      <ValidationTextField
        label="CSS validation style"
        required
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue="Success"
        id="validation-outlined-input"
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <>
              <IconButton>
                <ClearIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          )
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I did experiment with what exactly breaks it and I found that I can add normal HTML Elements in the endAdornment and it works fine, but when I add a mui component like the IconButton it breaks.